# How to Connect to the SQL server running in Docker on Windows 10 using MSSQL

Tags: sql-server, docker, docker-machine, sql-server-2017, docker-desktop

I have a running container in my docker machine.[image]

And I have set the port as 1423.

Then I'm using MSSQL client to connect with this container.

I used the IP address comes with host.docker.internal in the host file (C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc). And use the port as 1423.
ex: `172.1.1.1,1423` as the server name in the MSSQL.

But I'm not able to connect to that.

expecting a way to connect to this container using MSSQL.

Comment: The `-p` parameter is publishing to ports on your host machine (Windows 10), so try connecting to your machine's IP address on port 1423, or localhost on port 1423. e.g.: From a PowerShell prompt, `docker run -e "ACCEPT_EULA=Y" -e "SA_PASSWORD=YourStr0ngPassw0rd" -h sql5 --name sql5 -p 0.0.0.0:1423:1433 -d mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2017-latest` Then, from SSMS, connect to server name: `127.0.0.1,1423` with SQL Server authentication using `sa` and password `YourStr0ngPassw0rd`.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning I tried that, but still I'm unable to connect.